# There will be Jay, Jenny and I/me/myself at dinner

Tags: pronouns, dummy-pronouns

> There will be Jay, Jenny and **I/me/myself** at dinner.

Which is the most formal here?

EDIT: I just realized there are two more options here using the reflexive pronoun ["to add emphasis to the pronouns *I* or *me*"](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/myself), as in *[They took me '''myself''' prisoner](https://books.google.es/books?id=-EV6Knffp58C&lpg=PA8&dq=%22took%20me%20myself%22&hl=es&pg=PA8#v=onepage&q=%22took%20me%20myself%22&f=false)* -the elision of  those pronouns leaves the reflexive alone in the third option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [First-person pronouns in coordinate subjects - "Bob and myself are..."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56561/first-person-pronouns-in-coordinate-subjects-bob-and-myself-are)

Answer (score 0):

To figure out which declension of **I** is correct, remove the other subjects:

1. There will be **I** at dinner.
2. There will be **me** at dinner.
3. There will be **myself** at dinner.

"There" is the subject, "will be" is the main verb, the pronoun referring to the speaker is the object, and "at dinner" is an adverbial prepositional phrase modifying the verb "will be."

The only correct option is Option 2, **me**. This is the object form of the pronoun **I**. **Myself** is the *reflexive case* of the pronoun **I** and does not make sense in this context.

> There will be Jay, Jenny and me at dinner.

But this sentence sounds awkward to my ear. I would put the people first in the sentence and make them the subjects:

> Jay, Jenny and I will be at dinner.

Comment: I disagree. You wouldn't say "There will be I". Beginning the sentence with "There" seems fine to me if the question was "How many of the household will be in for dinner tonight?" "There will be Jay, Jenny and me." The idea that using _myself_ in a statement somehow makes it more formal and 'correct' is erroneous.

Comment: @KateBunting you're right, of course. Edited.

Comment: _the pronoun referring to the speaker is the object_, the object of the verb _to be_?

Comment: @GJC yes... but the more I think about it the more I disagree with Kate. "There will be I" sounds archaic but is grammatically correct, I believe.

Comment: The case of the complement of "to be": if the pronominal complement is immediately (or soon
afterwards) followed by _who/that_  the subject case is still
frequently used in formal styles: _it was **he** who would be
waiting on the towpath_. The formally correct nominative is still found in fairly
formal writing: _If anyone could write about the narcissistic
personality, it was **she**_—NY Rev. Bks, 1987