# I vs me with "there are"

Tags: pronouns

Which of these sentences is correct and why?:

1. There will be three people: he, she and me.
2. There will be three people, he, she and I.

In this example the three people are the subject or the object?

I'm using the tool "Grammarly" and it is suggesting that "me" would be correct but it seems to me that "I" is the right option.  I would say that the three people are the subject.

Apparently both sentences might be said by native speakers despite the difference regarding the type of pronoun between "he" or "she" and "me".

Comment: Most natives wouldn't be able to get this one right every time. 'Him, her & me' would be just as likely to be thrown in the mix ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [First-person pronouns in coordinate subjects - "Bob and myself are..."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56561/first-person-pronouns-in-coordinate-subjects-bob-and-myself-are)

Comment: "I" preferred. The subject is "there". "He", "she" and "I" is a noun phrase coordination functioning as a supplement; a loosely attached expression presenting supplementary non-integrated content.

Comment: @Joachim that question helps but still I have the doubt. The tool "Grammarly" is suggesting that "me" is the correct option but it seems to me that "I" should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary thing to consider here is that the pronouns must be of the same type; that is, all must be nominative or all must be objective. The most professional way to say this is "he, she, and I," but "him, her, and me" is used occasionally.

Comment: The subject is "there". "He", "she" and "I" is a noun phrase functioning as a supplement; a loosely attached expression presenting supplementary non-integrated content.

Comment: @Eli Harold I agree that the type of the pronouns must coincide. Please see the edited question.  Is it common to used "me" like in sentence number 1 although it is incorrect?

Comment: @gyerena "he, she, and I" is what I would use, but when looking at specifically what would be commonly used I don't think either would be the most popular. Usually you wouldn't refer to 2 different people with pronouns, usually the pronoun is used with the listener(s) knows who you are speaking of and you can refer to him/her as "he/she." I think the most common use would be: "he, Hannah, and I" or "him, Hannah, and I" (even though pronouns aren't agreeing). Since all of this is quite odd, natives such as myself would instead completely change the sentence to: "there will just be the 3 of us"

Comment: Other options are "me and them two" "me, john, and her." The thing that makes this all so confusing is these options are all only used for 2 people. When listing people such as: "This project will have 5 engineers, John, James, Sarah, Hannah, and myself." **myself** is used and would be considered the most idiomatic.

Comment: @gyerena Now that I think of it, "There will be three people: him, her, and myself" actually sounds quite normal also. I am getting off topic a little here, but maybe this helps you to understand, idk. Long story short: "he, she and I" is more correct, but "he, she and me can be used although it wouldn't be common, both of these are uncommon, and completely rewording the sentence is probably the only way to find a great and idiomatic phrase. A good alternative would be: "John, Sarah, and I will be the only three people there" as using names is the best way to address more than one person.

Comment: @Eli Harold In fact I was writing an email with this sentence: "There will be 3 people in total for the new project: X (name), his coworker and me". Then I started to doubt and noticed that the tool "Grammarly" accepted "me" as correct and marked "I" as incorrect.  I let "me" and then posted this question here.

Comment: @gyerena I see, the reason it does that is because "me" is used when the phrase is at the end of the sentence (yours is) "I" is used when at the start of the sentence (rule of thumb I heard somewhere, maybe it's true). Also "me" is usually the first of the list. So in your case the best option would be: "There will be 3 people in total for the new project: Me, John, and John's co-worker." If you know the name of "his co-worker" I would highly recommend using it: "There will be 3 people in total for the new project: Me, John, and John's co-worker, Sarah."